# Selecting a filtered array of optional objects

Tags: angular, angular8

I'm pretty new to Angular and I'm having a hard time figuring this out. I have a part ID, and I'm trying to select all of the (optional) company objects that have the same part ID.

```
export class Part {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    company?: Company[];
}

...

public parts: Part[];
public filteredCompanies: Company[];

...

public filterCompanies(): void {
    this.filteredCompanies = this.parts.filter(part => part.id === retrievedID).map(part => part.company);
}
```

The following line is giving me an error with a red squiggly line under `this.filteredCompanies`:

```
Type 'Company[][]' is not assignable to type 'Company[]'. Type 'Company[]' is missing the following properties from type 'Company': id, name, description, ...
```

I thought the syntax was right, but I'm definitely missing something.

Comment: What is `part.capability`? Did you mean `part.company`?

Comment: Is it a typo that you are mapping `part.capability` instead of `part.company` ? Does this code compiles ?

Comment: @ConnorsFan Sorry yes, that was supposed to be company.

Comment: @Treycos The code doesn't compile, I'm getting a red squiggly line under "this.filteredCompanies".

Comment: do you have field `retrievedID` in filterCompanies method..? is that causing the error...

Comment: @ganesh045 `retrievedID` is a number that I'm getting from somewhere else within the method. I left it out because I thought it wasn't necessary to leave in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code returns an array of `Company[]`, each one coming from a filtered `Part`. You can convert the `Company[][]` to a `Company[]` by calling the [flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) method:

```
this.filteredCompanies = this.parts.filter(...).map(part => part.company || []).flat();
```

Since `flat` is not available in Internet Explorer, you can use one of the alternatives suggested in the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) if you need to support that browser. Here is one possible alternative:

```
this.filteredCompanies = this.parts.filter(...).map(part => part.company || [])
                                   .reduce((acc, val) => acc.concat(val), [])
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rtf3dc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) for a demo.

Comment: What library/import is `flat` under?

Comment: `flat` is a method of `Array`.

Comment: Tried the `reduce` and `concat` alternative instead in my code, but a console.log shows the result as undefined. I do see it working in the StackBlitz demo though, just wondering if there's any other modifications I have to make to my code...

Comment: I made a change in the code to account for cases where the optional `Part.company` would be `undefined` or `null`. Please provide a stackblitz if it doesn't solve your problem.

Comment: `map` was returning undefined. Took a while to figure out, but the JSON I was using to get the Part data had one name/property that didn't match up. `company?` should've been `companies?`, and everything worked.